# Can one instance variable access another in the same class?

Tags: ruby, chess

I am writing a chess engine in Ruby.

I have a `Game` class, which consists of two attributes:

- `:board`, an instance of my `Board` class.
- :log, an array of moves, for saving & loading games.

The `Board` class consists of two attributes:

- `:white`, an instance of my `Player` class.
- `:black`, an instance of my `Player` class.

The `Player` class consists of piece locations,  represented as bitstrings:

```
:pawns, :knights, ..., :king
```

I would like the `Player` class to have methods like `in_check?` to indicate if that player is in check. However, that requires, `@white` to know the values of `@black,` which is an instance back in the `Board` class.

Is there a way I can access the variable `@black` from `@white` without explicitly passing the locations of the black pieces as a parameter to the `in_check` method?

Answer (score 1):

Let `@white` and `@black` respectively ask the board about the check.

---

Update:

Well, I guess there are a lot of assumptions here on my side, so lets write these down and see whether we have some common ground:

```
class Board

  def initialize
    ...
    @black = Player.new(self, other_args*)
    @white = Player.new(self, other_args*)
    ...
  end

  def am_i_in_check?(player)
    case player
    when @black
      return does_white_check_black?
    when @white
      return does_black_check_white?
    end
  end

  ...
end

class Player
  ...
  def initialize(board,...)
    ...
    @board=board
    ...
  end
  ...

  def wants_to_know_whether_it_is_checked
    @board.am_i_in_check?(self)
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

I guess there are typos hidden above, but it should describe my idea now.

Comment: Do you mean have methods like "white_in_check?" and "black_in_check?" in the board class? 

Oh or maybe one called "in_check" that returns "white" or "black" or nil.

Comment: Why not "am_i_in_check?"? The board knows, it can decide who asked the question and who is the oponent.

Comment: Good point. How does a player ask the board? If it was getting a constant, it would be something like ::Board::SOMECONSTANT. Is calling a method done similarly?

But this is basically still my original question.

Comment: Wow, thanks for being so detailed.

This is more or less what I have implemented now.

Is there no way to explicitly have black get information about white via a method inside of the black class?

Comment: Each player could have a reference to the other using a property like 'opponent' which the board would set after initializing the players. But it seems cleaner to give the board object the responsibility for analyzing this state (IMHO).

Answer (score 1):

The first player can pass message `"you're in check"` to another player after or before making a step.
The accessing variables is not a good idea, it leads to the future problems, pass messages instead.

Comment: I thought of this, and I discounted this idea for the following reason. If I start from a non-initial position--like from a loaded game state--I would like to be able to determine if a player is in check from reading the current board.

Comment: @mwatson In that case, the log should tell you the last player and move at resume, at which point checking for check should also be done.

Comment: True, that would work. I would still need a check if I wanted to allow editing the board to start a game from a specified layout, without having played up to that point. However, I am not even close to thinking about that yet.